# In UITableView, what's the delegate for "visibleCells"?

Tags: ios, uitableview

When cells come in and out of device's screen, I want my viewController to know exactly what came and what went out.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Aren't you already using     override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell function to load your cells? That's the place where your view controller notices the cell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a delegate method just for "visible cells". There isn't anything called when a cell leaves the screen. There really isn't anything when a cell becomes visible.

There is the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` data source method. This is called when a cell is needed.

There is the `willDisplayRowAtIndexPath` delegate method. This is called when a cell will be displayed.

There is the `didEndDisplayingCell` delegate method. This is called when a cell is removed from the table view.

There is the `indexPathsForVisibleRows` method on `UITableView`. This lets you know what rows are currently in view.

There is the `prepareForReuse` method on `UITableViewCell`. This lets a cell reset itself to be reused for another row.

Better describe what you are trying to accomplish in order to get a more specific answer.

Comment: You can also use `-tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` to track when a cell is no longer visible.

Comment: `willDisplayRowAtIndexPath` = "what came" 
`didEndDisplayingCell` = "what went out"

Comment: @rmaddy I'm trying to add/remove firebase references when the user scrolls. Since I have a long list, I cannot hold on to hundreds of firebase references, so I need to create/remove them when people scroll.

Comment: I'm not sure what references you mean but simply assign a reference to each cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. The table view will only create enough cells to be visible (maybe one extra). So you'll never need more than a dozen (roughly) references since there won't ever be more cells than that.