# How can my UITableViewCell know when it will be displayed and destroyed?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

As the user scrolls down the tableView, the cells are being dequeued and queued.

I'd like to know, inside my UITableViewCell, when this happens.

If it's not possible, could we use notification centers to achieve this (using the delegates of the table view?)

Note: I want the cell **itself** to know when it's being dequeued.
I know that there is already 2 delegates from UITableView I can use, but I rather not use those.

Comment: How is this different to your previous question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957992/in-uitableview-whats-the-delegate-for-visiblecells ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar task and I came to using this methods:

```
override func willMoveToSuperview(_ newSuperview: UIView?)
{
    super.willMoveToSuperview(newSuperview)
    if newSuperview != nil
    {
        // Cell will be added to collection view
    }
    else
    {
        // Cell will be removed
    }
}

override func didMoveToSuperview()
{
    // You can also override this method, check self.superview
}
```

As I remember these methods worked much more stable than `prepareForReuse()`. But the delegate methods are more robust anyway.

Comment: in many cases, unfortunately, this does not work - it's already in the superview, and the table view system slides it in to the screen...

Answer (score 0):

When a cell is no longer needed, it's removed from the `UITableView`, in order to detect when this happens you can override the `removeFromSuperView` method. However when you're scrolling, cells get reused, so you also need to do the same cleanup in prepareForReuse.

As for detecting when it was added to the table view, you can add a `configure` method that gets called by `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, as most likely you anyhow need to implement `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    func configure(obj: MyDataObject) {
        // intialize whathever you need
    }

    func doCleanup() {
        // cleanup the stuff you need
    }

    override func removeFromSuperview() {
        super.removeFromSuperview()
        doCleanup()
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        doCleanup()
    }
}
```